# Autoload class with php with an ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, autoload

I have a function for autoloading my classes in the header file. So when my page loads, i am able to autoload my class and use it in the body of my code. But i have a ajax request which reloads only a part of my page. At this time the autoload function is not working cause its in my header. How do i make the autoload class to work while i am reloading only a part of my page.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add autoloader to the script that processes your AJAX request.

Remember: there is no such thing as 'reloading only a part of my page'. Each request is handled entirely on its own.